# Bash script to crosscheck list of names with a firewall config file

Tags: bash, firewall, python, bash-scripting, perl

I am looking to automate something with a script in bash or python.

Let's say I have a config file from a device. A simple config.txt file. Content could be like this (actual file is much longer and has much more text):

```
> cat config.txt
> 
> ASA Version 9.1(5) 
> !
> terminal width 511
> hostname confidential
> domain-name confidential
> enable password  encrypted
> passwd  encrypted
> names
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet0/0
>  nameif interconnection
>  security-level 50
>  ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.240 standby 1.1.1.1 
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet0/1
>  description Trunk
>  no nameif
>  no security-level
>  no ip address
> !
> interface GigabitEthernet0/1.4
>  description confidential
>  vlan 4
>  nameif vlan004_confidential
>  security-level 50
>  ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0 
> !
> object network confidential
>  host 2.2.2.2
> object network confidential2
>  host 3.3.3.3
> object network confidential3
>  host 4.4.4.4
>!
>access-list vlan65_access_in extended permit object-group confidential any object-group confidential 
>access-list vlan65_access_in remark Allow ICMP OK-20131105
>access-list vlan65_access_in extended permit icmp any object vlan48-confidential 
>access-list vlan65_access_in remark Allow NTP OK-20131105
>access-list vlan65_access_in extended permit udp any object-group confidential eq ntp 
>access-list warehouse_access_in remark Access to confidential
>access-list warehouse_access_in extended permit object-group confidential any object-group confidential 
>access-list warehouse_access_in remark Access to DNS srvrs
>access-list warehouse_access_in extended permit ip any object-group DNS_Servers 
>access-list warehouse_access_in remark Allow acces to AD
>!
>no pager
>logging enable
>logging timestamp
>logging standby
>logging list SysLogs message 304001
>logging list connections message 302013-302304
>logging list NewConnection message 302303
>logging list NewConnection message 302015
>logging list NewConnection message 302013
>logging list NewConnection message 303002
>logging list Dropped message 106001-106103
>logging list ConfigChange message 111008
>logging list ConfigChange message 111001
>logging list ConfigChange message 111010
>logging buffer-size 1048576
>logging monitor debugging
>logging buffered warnings
>!
>access-group vlan4_access_in in interface vlan004_confidential1
>access-group vlan65_access_in in interface vlan065_confidential2
>access-group vlan66_access_in in interface vlan066_confidential3
>access-group vlan80_access_in in interface vlan080_confidential4
>!
>service-policy global_policy global
>service-policy test interface interconnection
>service-policy imec_intranet_traffic-policy interface vlan065_confidential5
>service-policy imec_intranet_traffic-policy interface vlan066_confidential6
>service-policy imec_intranet_traffic-policy interface vlan080_confidential7
>service-policy imec_intranet_traffic-policy interface vlan082_confidential8
>service-policy imec_intranet_traffic-policy interface vlan083_confidential9
>!
>: end
```

My second file is a list (list.txt). And the content and layout is something like this (in notepad++):

list.txt

```
>username    full name                       employid  group           left comp on
>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>test16    confidential1                        00014241  zzzz1             19-08-2017
>test38    confidential2                        00014223  zzzz2             12-08-2017
>test47    confidential3                        00013986  zzzz3             06-07-2017
>test85    confidential4                        00013923  zzzz4             16-07-2017
```

Is it possible to run a script that takes every word in the "username" and "full name" column in the list.txt file and check if there is a match in the config.txt file? It would be great to have the output of the script in a third file that mentions what word (here username or full name) is found in the config.txt file and where.

Let's say I want to know if test38 is somewhere in the config.txt file? I now I can simply grep, but my list.txt file has around 100 users. I don't want to grep 100 times. On top of that, I'll get more lists in the future.

Comment: What is the format of each file? Could add an extract, of course without real names?

Comment: For the list I could use csv, xls, txt. The config output of the Cisco ASA is just a file on a linux box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64941/discussion-between-maxim-and-toto).

Comment: You could pass to `grep -f` a file with the words to search, could be `grep -FnH -f <( sed -nr 's/^>([[:alnum:]]+) +([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1\n\2/p' list.txt ) config.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a perl script that does the job, (as far as I understand):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $config  = 'config.txt';   # give the full path
my $list    = 'list.txt';     # give the full path
my $outfile = 'outfile.txt';  # give the full path

# read list file and store in a hash
open my $fhl, '<', $list or die "unable to open '$list': $!";
my %users;
while(my $line = <$fhl>) {
    next if $. < 3;     # skip first 2 lines (header)
    my ($user, $name) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $users{$user} = $name if $user and $name;
}
close $fhl;

open my $fhc, '<', $config or die "unable to open '$config': $!";
open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "unable to open '$outfile': $!";
# read config line by line
while(my $line = <$fhc>) {
    # loop on all users
    while( my ($u,$n) = each(%users)) {
        # print outputfile if user found 
        print $out "$u:$n found line $.\n" if $line =~ /\b($u|$n)\b/;
    }
}
```

**outputfile for given example**

```
test38:confidential2 found line 30
test47:confidential3 found line 32
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'll make time today to test it, make changes if necessary and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Very nice! Works from first time. I will try to understand what you did here because I am not good at scripting and programming. Is it also possible to get rid of the empty lines ": found line x"? I have +7000 lines now. How could I make the script that it only returns the matches?
Anyway this helps me already a lot. So thank you very much!

Comment: @maxim: You're welcome, glad it helps. Sorry, I don't get you about empty lines,the script print on outputfile only if there is a match. Do you means there are empty lines in list.txt ?

Comment: No empty lines in list.txt. But the outfile writes every line of my config.txt file as for example ": found line 7081". It starts at 1 and ends at 7114. The config.txt file counts 7114 lines too. Between these 7114 lines in the outfile I can see the matches like this: "schaba27:confidential found line 5319".

Comment: @maxim: Change `$users{$user} = $name ;` into `$users{$user} = $name if $user and $name;`, see my edit.

Comment: @maxim: or, just after the while loop `while( my ($u,$n) = each(%users)) {`, add the line: `next unless $u and $n;`

Comment: :-o did exactly what I asked. I wish I had your perl level :-p.

Comment: @maxim: Happy it works for you. Feel free to mark answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

According to my personal understanding about your requestion, I use builtin command `while` and command `awk` to solve it.

directly output

```
awk 'NR>2{print $1,$2}' list.txt | while IFS=" " read -r username fullname; do awk -v name="${username}" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}match($0,/'"${fullname}"'/){gsub(/>/,"",name);print name,NR,$0}' config.txt; done
```

write output to file `output.txt`

```
awk 'NR>2{print $1,$2}' list.txt | while IFS=" " read -r username fullname; do awk -v name="${username}" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}match($0,/'"${fullname}"'/){gsub(/>/,"",name);print name,NR,$0>>"output.txt"}' config.txt; done
```

output format is

```
user name|line no.|match content
```

Result output

```
test16|64|>access-group vlan4_access_in in interface vlan004_confidential1
test38|30|> object network confidential2
test38|65|>access-group vlan65_access_in in interface vlan065_confidential2
test47|32|> object network confidential3
test47|66|>access-group vlan66_access_in in interface vlan066_confidential3
test85|67|>access-group vlan80_access_in in interface vlan080_confidential4
```